# Failing to install @core to an Angular 11 project

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install, angular11

The problem I'm facing is that i need to use '@core/interfaces/multi-select-item-data', in a Angular 11 project. So I tried to run:

```
npm i @core
```

It seemed to have installed a few packages, and skipped a few optional dependencies. But it happens that when I open my node_modules folder, the subfolder @core is not there, and the import to '@core/interfaces/multi-select-item-data' still has the same error on it, which is: "Cannot find module '@core/interfaces/multi-select-item-data' or its corresponding type declarations".

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem apparently was being caused by the CDK and material modules of angular.

try to run the following commands:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: I've tried to do this with @core, but the second command does not seem do work here. It says that rf is not a valid command

Comment: @PedroHenriqueGomes try `-r` (instead of `rf`)

Comment: Now the terminal says that 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: remove `node_modules` manually, and then try `npm install`

Comment: I did it, but It didn't work, the @core folder is still not showing in the node_modules...